# RewriteRule for static files in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following folder structure for my website:

```
index.php
.htaccess
public_html/css/* (css files)
public_html/images/* (image files)
public_html/js/* (javascript files)
```

All the static files in the subfolder public_html are linked in my page files without public_html: e.g. /images/logo/logo.png

I setup following .htaccess file, which is working fine on my local apache and on my webspace, but on the customers webspace, it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public_html/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/public_html/
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public_html/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

must be rewritten to (2 possibilities)

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public_html%{REQUEST_URI} -f
# or
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public_html/$1 -f
```

Also, you don't need leading slash `/` before `public_html` in `RewriteRule` since you already defined it in `RewriteBase`.

Then, this line

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/public_html/
```

must be rewritten to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public_html/
```

typo error (replace `$` by `%`).

**Conclusion**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public_html/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public_html/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your corrections, but the changes do not work. The images, css and js are still missing (404 (Not Found) message).

Comment: Are you sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and htaccess allowed on your customer webspace ?

Comment: I think .htaccess is allowed, because when I comment the line RewriteBase /, I get a 500 error page. But I am not sure, if any other apache setting is blocking the correct rewrite?!

Comment: Can you check in apache error logs and rewrite logs ?