# How to get /folder/subfolder to display as /subfolder/ using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rename

I'm trying to do the following...

**Original path that needs to be rewritten, renamed, or redirected:**

`http://www.example.com/_plugin/notifications/`

**to:**

`http://www.example.com/notifications/`

via root htaccess file...Any help would be greatly appreciated!

=================================================================

This does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/_plugin/notifications$ /notifications [L]
```

This does not work either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch ^/_plugin/notifications$ /notifications/
```

This does not work either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^notifications/(.*)$ /notifications$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

=============================

**EDIT**

With the help of @Starkeen - I have a few follow up questions to this.

1. Is there a way to shorten the .htaccess file up though if lets say I
   have multiple subfolders within the folder instead of writing that 1
   condition and the 2 rules for each subfolder?
2. How would I allow subfolders of the subfolder to display? Currently it is throwing a 404 at me... :(

============

Still need help with follow-up question #1, but I believe I got question #2.

**SOLUTION (I believe) to follow-up question #2:**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /_plugin/notifications/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^_plugin/notifications/(.*)$ /notifications/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^notifications/(.*)$ /_plugin/notifications/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686583/rewriterule-for-static-files-in-subfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the rules you have tried are correct. 
To redirect `/folder/subfolder` to `/root/subfolder` you need a permanent 301 Redirect rule something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/$ /subfolder/ [L,R]
```

The above will redirect `http://example.com/folder/subfolder/` to `http://example.com/subfolder` . 
You will get a 404 error if the `/subfolder/` doesn't exist in the root dir. To avoid the 404 error you can rewrite the `/subfolder/` uri back to its original location `/folder/subfolder/`  using an internal `Rewrite` just bellow the first one
:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/?$ /folder/subfolder/ [L]
```

Comment: This is working! Thank you very much! A follow-up or two questions if possible: Is there a way to shorten the .htaccess file up though if lets say I have multiple subfolders within the folder instead of writing that 1 condition and the 2 rules for each subfolder?

Also, how would I allow subfolders of the subfolder to display?  Currently it is throwing a 404 at me... :(

Comment: Please see edit to my original question posted.  Thx :)